# Do i need to use has in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Mark is no longer an employee and he resigned. After that Mark was registered in a tournament by someone. Two people are talking about how Mark was registered in the tournament. Is it:-

No. Only one person could have registered Mark after he has resigned and given him explosives.

or

No. Only one person could have registered Mark after he resigned and given him explosives.

or

Both are correct.

Comment: Both are somewhat confusing on their own.

Comment: can i use with has and without has? both are correct?

Comment: What does "explosives" have to do with anything?

Comment: Like @shadishtaklef said: both are pretty odd, but I'd say the second one works anyway. The first one is ungrammatical.

Comment: It would be much more natural if the sentence order were changed. *No. After Mark resigned, only one person could have registered him and given him explosives.*